# How to create an Even Odd Number Series formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula

is there a way to automatically fill a column with the following sequence:

| Column A: | Column B |
| --- | --- |
| Sku.100 | ck.1 |
| Sku.100 | ck.1 |
| Sku.101 | ck.1 |
| Sku.102 | ck.2 |
| Sku.102 | ck.2 |
| Sku.103 | ck.2 |
| Sku.104 | ck.3 |
| Sku.104 | ck.3 |
| Sku.105 | ck.3 |

Column A Twice even numbers, then 1 odd number
Column B series of 3 same numbers
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sir, 1000 range..

Comment: Excel 365 Versiyon

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming there is no `Excel Version Constraints`, you could try this using `SEQUENCE()` function.

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell `A1`

```
=LET(
    x, "Sku." &
        TOCOL(
            SEQUENCE(
                1000,
                ,
                100,
                2
            ) + {0, 0, 1}
        ),
    y, "ck." &
        INT(
            SEQUENCE(
                ROWS(x),
                ,
                ,
                1 / 3
            )
        ),
    HSTACK(x, y)
)
```

---

Comment: exactly the solution I was looking for. thanks for your attention

Comment: BTW if you want to change the range like increase or decrease then you can change the value of 1000 to whatever range you want

Comment: @MayukhBhattacharya this is a nice trick too: `+ {0, 0, 1}`to generate the desired sequence.